# What would make my question more constructive?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Any suggestions for what would make my question more constructive?

[Web apps/services to outsource various website functionality](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24021/web-apps-services-to-outsource-various-website-functionality)

I am really not smartassing nor promoting my website, I am just trying to learn something new and get some inspiration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be more off topic than not constructive. It's about marketing a website and the tools one would find to use. In spirit it would be better on Pro Webmasters or OnStartups from the web building and site launch aspects respectively

Why it's also not constructive is due to its "help me build my website" parts. Where you're looking for web apps to suit a cause instead of help with a specific web app or service.